# Is it possible for a wild parthenogenic dodo to exist in real earth?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, fauna, avian

so imagine, there's parthenogenic species of dodos that lives in a remote island with no predators or man have never set foot, it has some similar traits of a brush turkey (not an actual turkey), like burying its eggs with compost and having their chicks taking care of themselves once they're hatched, although there will be only hens (and no roosters have ever found).

**Is it possible for a parthenogenic dodo to exist in real earth? and also how long can it able to hatch?**

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you world-building? Does the biology of this world only resemble Earth, or is it an alternate Earth? In the real world, there are already several parthenogenic species (reptiles, no birds I'm aware of). It's not just plausible, but almost certain that this could be engineered even in the real world. For an alien biology, the rules are so relaxed, that you can do nearly anything you like without it becoming unbelievable.

Comment: Well, [whiptail lizards](https://www.nationalgeographic.org/article/how-asexual-lizard-procreates-alone/) can do it, so your dodos might have a chance.

Comment: This question suggests a lack of research. VTC.

Comment: Lack of research. The wikipedia article answers this question rather specifically, with hardly any searching at all.

Comment: @JohnO Yep, [it exists](https://www.embies.com/parthenogenesis-in-birds-a-review/), but generally produces only males, when they live.

Answer (score 4):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenogenesis#Birds):

> Parthenogenesis in birds is known mainly from studies of domesticated turkeys and chickens, although it has also been noted in the domestic pigeon. In most cases the egg fails to develop normally or completely to hatching. The first description of parthenogenetic development in a passerine was demonstrated in captive zebra finches, although the dividing cells exhibited irregular nuclei and the eggs did not hatch.
>
> Parthenogenesis in turkeys appears to result from a conversion of haploid cells to diploid; most embryos produced in this way die early in development. Rarely, viable birds result from this process, and the rate at which this occurs in turkeys can be increased by selective breeding, however male turkeys produced from parthenogenesis exhibit smaller testes and reduced fertility

Parthenogenesis is viable in some reptiles, including snakes and alligators. There is nothing to suggest it would be implausible for birds (of any class) to be viably parthenogenic.